# WHERE clause operator based on column value

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause, dynamic-sql

I'd like to have a table which contains values to compare against **and** operator to use (`=`, `!=`, `~`, `!~` etc). For example:

```
CREATE TABLE rule (
    value1 varchar NOT NULL,
    op1 varchar NOT NULL,
    value2 varchar NOT NULL,
    op2 varchar NOT NULL,
    ...
);
```

What I want can be described with this pseudo code:

```
SELECT * FROM rule WHERE value1 op1 ?;
```

In the example, I've stored the operator in a separate column, but I am open to other solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL is static language that does not allow to parameterize anything but *values*. You'd need some form of *dynamic* SQL - which burns down to concatenating a query string that is executed in turn.

You could make your whole `SELECT` statement dynamic with a server-side PL/pgSQL function. Or with any client-side logic, which entails an additional round-trip to the server, though.

Or just make the evaluation dynamic by encapsulating that part in a function:

```
CREATE TABLE the_rule (
   value1 text NOT NULL
 , op1    text NOT NULL
 , value2 text NOT NULL
 , op2    text NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO the_rule VALUES
   ('foo','=','bar','<')
 , ('baz','<','bam','>');


CREATE FUNCTION rule_eval(_val text, _opr text, _arg text
                        , OUT _pass bool) AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format('SELECT %L %s %L', _val, _opr, _arg)
   INTO _pass;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * FROM the_rule
WHERE  rule_eval(value1, op1, 'foo')
AND    rule_eval(value2, op2, 'aaa');
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=63ce7a1668c0ed3e639c117361e19dbb)*

**However**, this kind of obfuscation largely prohibits performance-optimized execution plans. Such functions are black boxes to the the Postgres query planner, indexes cannot be used, for example.

And you are open to **SQL injection**. `_val`  and `_arg` are properly quoted in the example above, thereby making SQL injection impossible. But the *operator* cannot be quoted. You ***could*** use the object identifier type `regoperator` to guarantee valid operators - and cast to `regoper` and combine with the [`OPERATOR()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE) construct to get valid syntax. Like:

```
CREATE TABLE the_rule (
   value1 text NOT NULL
 , op1    regoperator NOT NULL
 , value2 text NOT NULL
 , op2    regoperator NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO the_rule VALUES
   ('foo', '=(text,text)', 'bar', '<(text,text)')
 , ('baz', '<(text,text)', 'bam', '>(text,text)');

CREATE FUNCTION rule_eval(_val text, _opr regoperator, _arg text
                        , OUT _pass bool) AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format('SELECT %L OPERATOR(%s) %L', _val, _opr::regoper, _arg)
   INTO _pass;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- Same query as above
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=6e85de36df21587f1c001f78ef32551f)*

Now, SQL injection is impossible. But we have introduced more complexity, yet. And I am not sure `reoperator` stays valid across dump / restore cycles or  major version upgrades. (Probably better to persist the `text` representation after all.)

**Or** if you only allow a predetermined set of operators - with a FK constraint to a secure lookup table or an `enum` type or just a plain `CHECK` constraints for a hand full of allowed operators. Like:

```
CREATE TABLE the_rule (
   value1 text NOT NULL
 , op1    text NOT NULL CHECK (op1 = ANY ('{>,>=,=,<=,<}'))
 , value2 text NOT NULL
 , op2    text NOT NULL CHECK (op2 = ANY ('{>,>=,=,<=,<}'))
);

INSERT INTO the_rule VALUES
   ('foo', '=', 'bar', '<')
 , ('baz', '<', 'bam', '>');

CREATE FUNCTION rule_eval(_val text, _opr text, _arg text
                        , OUT _pass bool) AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format('SELECT %L %s %L', _val, _opr, _arg)
   INTO _pass;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * FROM the_rule
WHERE  rule_eval(value1, op1, 'foo')
AND    rule_eval(value2, op2, 'aaa');
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=3700f5308e0040c253d47abd067e2cc6)*

Input from the table is secure but the function itself is an entry point for SQL injection now.

And we haven't even touched complications with different data *types*, yet.

In short: *possible*, but you need to know exactly what you are doing to deal with various kinds of possible complications. ***Typically, there is a simpler way to implement your requirements.***

Comment: Quite sufficient. Neither SQLi nor performance is an issue for my particular purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Here is explicit logic for solving this:

```
where (op1 = '=' and value1 = ?) or
      (op1 = '<' and value < ?) or
      . . .
```

Comment: Yeah, that's obvious. I was hoping there is a way without writing a case for every possible operator.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `OR` and `AND` in condition.

```
SELECT * 
FROM rule 
WHERE 
    (op1 = '=' AND value1 = ?) 
OR
    (op1 = '!=' AND value1 != ?)
```